# Unable to do access GAE server running on computer from Android device

Tags: android, eclipse, google-app-engine, adt

I'm trying out my first GAE server and Android connection. I'm running a GAE server through Android ADT on my computer(192.168.1.24). My Android device is connected in developer mode through USB. I'm trying to make a HTTP Request from the device and store the response. But I get the below error.

```
02-23 03:10:22.915: E/AndroidRuntime(18076): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-23 03:10:22.915: E/AndroidRuntime(18076): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not      execute method of the activity
02-23 03:10:22.915: E/AndroidRuntime(18076):    at     android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3838)
02-23 03:10:22.915: E/AndroidRuntime(18076):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
02-23 03:10:22.915: E/AndroidRuntime(18076):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18796)
02-23 03:10:22.915: E/AndroidRuntime(18076):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
02-23 03:10:22.915: E/AndroidRuntime(18076):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-23 03:10:22.915: E/AndroidRuntime(18076):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-23 03:10:22.915: E/AndroidRuntime(18076):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5455)
02-23 03:10:22.915: E/AndroidRuntime(18076):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-23 03:10:22.915: E/AndroidRuntime(18076):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-23 03:10:22.915: E/AndroidRuntime(18076):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
02-23 03:10:22.915: E/AndroidRuntime(18076):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
02-23 03:10:22.915: E/AndroidRuntime(18076):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-23 03:10:22.915: E/AndroidRuntime(18076): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-23 03:10:22.915: E/AndroidRuntime(18076):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-23 03:10:22.915: E/AndroidRuntime(18076):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-23 03:10:22.915: E/AndroidRuntime(18076):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3833)
02-23 03:10:22.915: E/AndroidRuntime(18076):    ... 11 more
02-23 03:10:22.915: E/AndroidRuntime(18076): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in scheme at index 0:     192.168.1.24:8889/myserver?username=qwerty&password=qwerty
02-23 03:10:22.915: E/AndroidRuntime(18076):    at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:727)
02-23 03:10:22.915: E/AndroidRuntime(18076):    at org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet.<init>(HttpGet.java:75)
02-23 03:10:22.915: E/AndroidRuntime(18076):    at httprequest.GetMethods.doGetWithResponse(GetMethods.java:28)
02-23 03:10:22.915: E/AndroidRuntime(18076):    at com.example.tandemstory.UserAuth.doAuth(UserAuth.java:24)
02-23 03:10:22.915: E/AndroidRuntime(18076):    at com.example.tandemstory.SignIn.onSignin(SignIn.java:74)
02-23 03:10:22.915: E/AndroidRuntime(18076):    ... 14 more
```

The statement that initiates the http request from Android device is below.

```
String alias=UserAuth.doAuth(username, password);
```

The UserAuth.doAuth() is as below

```
 public static String doAuth(String username,String password) {
    // CONSTRUCT GET REQUEST URL
    String url = "192.168.1.24/myserver?username=qwerty&password=qwerty"
    // XML RESPONSE AS A STRING GETS RETURNED
    String response = GetMethods.doGetWithResponse(URL_BASE, httpClient);

    return response;
}
```

The GetMethods.doGetWithResponse() is as below

```
public static String doGetWithResponse(String mUrl,DefaultHttpClient httpClient){
    String ret=null;
    HttpResponse response=null;
    //initiate get method with username and password
    HttpGet getMethod=new HttpGet(mUrl);
    try{
        //use http client to execute method
        response=httpClient.execute(getMethod);
        if(response!=null){
            //convert http response to string
            ret=getResponseBody(response);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Please give any pointers towards the solution.

Comment: Things I have done/tried -
(1) added --address=192.168.1.24 in the arguments tab in Run Configurations of my server. I can access the server using this IP address from my computer. But unable to access this from my device's browser(which is connected through USB in debugging mode).
(2) Disabled firewall on my computer.

Comment: l've tried this before without success. The only way i know is with android emulator that runs on the same machine as gae server and in android using 10.0.2.2 for localhost

Answer (score 0):

The exception `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in scheme at index 0:     192.168.1.24:8889/myserver?username=qwerty&password=qwerty` seems to indicate that a problem could be addressed by trying out the following:

- prefix your URL string with `http://` and see if that works.
- prefix your URL string with `http://` and also encode the URL correctly.